# How do we cluster using clustering coefficient? Any specific algorithm?

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis

I want to cluster my graph using local clustering coefficient.
I understand that a clustering coefficient measures how one node is likely to form a cluster, but I can't seem to find any specific clustering algorithm using clustering coefficient.

I tried to search for papers, but there seems to be not any relevant paper.
Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the clustering coefficient is not meant to be used for cluster analysis, but for network analysis. I.e. it measures the connectedness of nodes in a network, or how well a graph is expected to cluster.

Please also understand that "clustering" is a very broad term. Not every kind of cluster is interesting for every use case.

Using the clustering coefficient for cluster analysis may produce just results that you can already find with other methods, for example classic clique detection methods.